# How to get a string within an element from with Selenium for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am familiar with how to get an element by id, but how would I get "Microsoft Corporation" from this block using Selenium? I am using the Selenium to navigate through the page for other purposes:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="hdncompanyid" value="175650211"/>
<form action="/Subscriber/Bio/CompanyProfile" method="post" name="formPOST">    <script type="text/javascript">
        var companyName = "LinkedIn Corporation";
        var parentName = "Microsoft Corporation";
```

Comment: Use the XPath function

Comment: You would use a regular expression in this case to extract the data

Comment: why don't you use some plug-in like forepath fore firebug, so you can inspect the element and they will give you directly their Xpath and you will be able to easily identify the object!?